# jquery stop image rotation on mouseover, start on mouseout / hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have built a jQuery rotator to rotate through 3 divs and loop them.  I would like to add the functionality on mouse over to "freeze" the current div and then start again on mouse out.

I've thought about setting a variable to false at the start of the function and setting it true when it's on it's current frame but I've got my self a bit confused.

I've also tried to use the hover function but when using the in and out handlers, I'm confused as to how to stop, restart the animation.

```
  function ImageRotate() {
 var CurrentFeature = "#container" + featureNumber;

 $(CurrentFeature).stop(false, true).delay(4500).animate({'top' : '330px'}, 3000);


 var featureNumber2 = featureNumber+1;
 if ( featureNumber == numberOfFeatures) {featureNumber2 = 1}
 var NewFeature = "#container" + featureNumber2;
 $(NewFeature).stop(false, true).delay(4500).animate({'top' : '0px'}, 3000); 

 var featureNumber3 = featureNumber-1;
 if ( featureNumber == 1) {featureNumber3 = numberOfFeatures};
 var OldFeature = "#container" + featureNumber3;
 $(OldFeature).stop(false, true).delay(4500).css('top' , '-330px'); 

 setTimeout('if (featureNumber == numberOfFeatures){featureNumber = 1} else {featureNumber++}; ImageRotate2()', 7500)};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed things up a little bit, here is how I ended up doing it. `

```
 var animRun = false;
var rotateHover = false;

function startRotation() {

            rotateHover = false;
            ImageRotate();
        }

    function stopRotation() {
        rotateHover = true;
        clearTimeout();
    }

    function ImageRotate() {

    if (rotateHover == false){
    animRun = true;

    var CurrentFeature = "#container" + featureNumber;

    $(CurrentFeature).stop(false, true).animate({'top' : '330px'}, featureDuration, function(){animRun = false;});

    var featureNumber2 = featureNumber+1;
    if ( featureNumber == numberOfFeatures) {featureNumber2 = 1}
    var NewFeature = "#container" + featureNumber2;
    $(NewFeature).stop(false, true).animate({'top' : '0px'}, featureDuration); /* rotate slide 2 into main frame */

    var featureNumber3 = featureNumber-1;
    if ( featureNumber == 1) {featureNumber3 = numberOfFeatures};
    var OldFeature = "#container" + featureNumber3;
    $(OldFeature).stop(false, true).css('top' , '-330px'); /*bring slide 3 to the top*/

    //startRotation();

    setTimeout('if (featureNumber == numberOfFeatures){featureNumber = 1} else {featureNumber++}; if (rotateHover == false){ImageRotate2()};', featureDelay);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to add this code:

```
var timerId = null;
function startRotation() {
    if (timerId) {
        return;
    }
    timerId = setInterval('if (featureNumber == numberOfFeatures){featureNumber = 1} else {featureNumber++}; ImageRotate2()', 7500);
}
function stopRotation() {
    if (!timerId) {
        return;
    }
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = null;
}
```

and replace the last line of your code block with a simple call to `startRotation();`, then you could call `stopRotation` and `startRotation` when the mouse hovers over/leaves your element:

```
$('your-element-selector').hover(stopRotation, startRotation);
```

Comment: actually, for whatever reason, if you hover over it (it stops correctly).. then starts again on mouse out, but then once the next slide comes in, it's paused until you hover on and off again..

Comment: Fixed by changing `setTimeout` to `setInterval`.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do with the three divs without seeing the HTML and more code, so I think a basic example might help you better ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hRNrL/)).

HTML

```
<div class="test">image: <span></span></div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var indx = 0, loop, numberOfFeatures = 5;

 function imageRotate(){
  indx++;
  if (indx > numberOfFeatures) { indx = 1; }
  $('.test span').text(indx);
  loop = setTimeout( imageRotate , 1000 );
 }
 imageRotate();

 $('.test').hover(function(){
  clearTimeout(loop);
 }, function(){
  imageRotate();
 });

})
```