# Stop rotation on mouse hover in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have written a function by which i want to stop rotation of three.js object on mouse hover.

```
function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
 raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.group );
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
  if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

    if (controls.AutoRotate) {
       controls.autoRotate = false;
    }     }
  }


}
```

Don't know why but the function is not working neither it is giving any error in the console.Can anybody tell whats the problem over here or suggest the possible solution to this problem. Its not working maybe because i am embedding DOM elements inside three.js and using css renderer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2695236/6448640

Comment: In three.js rotation happens through orbit control.js

Answer (score -1):

`controls.AutoRotate` does not exist so it will never be equal to true.

Comment: I have not posted the whole code here. controls.AutoRotate is set to True in init() function.

Comment: `controls.AutoRotate` is not the same thing as `controls.autoRotate`